# Use Python's ConfigParser to automatically remove options

Tags: python, configparser

When using ConfigParser to parse multiple configuration files at the same time, is it possible to have an option from the first file removed by the second, and not just have it's value changed?

Answer (score 0):

At best, I think you could change the option value to set it empty.